# Get Top Events from Google Analytics API python

Tags: python, api, events, google-analytics

I need to get [Top Events](http://prntscr.com/8kdhu0) (one category) from one of the app in Google Analytics. Can I do this with the help of [Analytics Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py) ? I didn't find a way "how" to do this.